# Move buttons up on keyboard open Android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, android-view

I have a card Layout that contains a ScrollView with an Edit inside of it, below that is 2 buttons.

I am having an issue that when I open the keyboard and type till there is enough text that the Edit begins to expand the Buttons get hidden under the Keyboard.

I would like to make it so that the buttons are always above the keyboard just like how the bottom of the EditText is always slightly above it.

My layout is as follows:

```
CardView
   LinearLayout(Vertical)
       ScrollView
           EditText
       ButtonsLayout
           Button
           Button

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
          >

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/buttonsLayout"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:layout_weight="1">


                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/et_1"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:ems="10"
                                android:hint="What&apos;s on your mind?"
                                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                                android:maxLength="300" />



            </ScrollView>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fabAttach"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="125dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="onAttachClicked"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_attach"
                    android:visibility="visible"

                    app:borderWidth="0dp" />


                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fabPost"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/fabAttach"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fabAttach"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="onPostSquawkClicked"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_send_white"

                    app:borderWidth="0dp" />


            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Thanks so much for any help! It's really got me

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `LinearLayout` with a `RelativeLayout`, align the `ScrollView` to the top of the new `RelativeLayout`, set the id of the buttons container (the other `RelativeLayout` to `buttonsLayout` - as expected by the `ScrollView`; on the same buttons container - align it to the bottom of the parent `RelativeLayout` and set its height to `wrap_content`):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/buttonsLayout"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="What&apos;s on your mind?"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                android:maxLength="300" />
        </ScrollView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttonsLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fabAttach"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="125dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="onAttachClicked"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_attach"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:borderWidth="0dp" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fabPost"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/fabAttach"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fabAttach"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="onPostSquawkClicked"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_send_white"
                app:borderWidth="0dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```